# Can "certain" imply a negative opinion about something/somebody?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

In Italian, if I say *Indossano certe scarpe.* (which Google Translate translates as "They wear certain shoes."), I would be expressing a negative opinion about the shoes, for example that the shoes are inappropriate for the place, or they make appear ridiculous who is wearing them. That doesn't happen with *Certe volte sono triste.* ("I sometimes am sad."), though.

Can "certain" imply a negative opinion about something/somebody?

Comment: kiam, since you know both Italian and English can you tell me if an Anglophone could translate "Indossano certe scarpe" in "Indossano scarpe sicure" (They wear safety shoes)?

Comment: No, English native speakers would not say _safety shoes_ to mean _certain shoes_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equivalent in English would be "a certain sort of shoes". This *may* be said with scorn, implying (without saying expressly) that the shoes are *of a sort* which is diagnostic of a vulgarity which one is too well-bred to name outright:

> "Oh, my dear, her hat! her frock! and shoes" her voiced dropped dramatically, "of a certain sort!"

But that is not by any means the usual or even a common use of "a certain sort". My impression is that is largely confined to fashionable circles of the first third or half of the 20th century; and since I was not of those circles I cannot say whether it was actually in use or merely imputed to them by novelists and playwrights.